# Parse JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have JSON file like this

```
{
   "Value":{
      "9824800036":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9127801433":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9127801368":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9127801458":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9127801485":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9814008909":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9814008920":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9814008911":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9814008910":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9116665832":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9814008955":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      },
      "9116666000":{
         "TZ":0,
         "AllowChange":3,
         "InCall":true,
         "OutCall":true,
         "BeginDT":"00:00:00",
         "EndDT":"23:59:59",
         "Days":127
      }
   },
   "Success":true,
   "Error":null,
   "Failure":false
}
```

How i can get

`"9814008920","9814008911","9814008910","9116665832","9814008955"`?

Comment: Use a library like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse the Json into .NET objects.

Comment: This json is invalid

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i using Json.Net but dont understand how i can get this values...

Comment: @Jim i understan, but need parse it...

Comment: If it isn't legal Json, you'll probably have to write your own parser.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen can you write example?

Comment: Write an example of a parser that parses quirky JSON? I think you're asking for a bit much, though @Jim is wrong. This JSON is valid.

Comment: @ZZnOB from where does this Json comes from ? Is it something you have wrote yourself, and have local (in a textfile or something) ?

Comment: @JLRishe i'm sorry it is not valid

Comment: @Jim no, this JSON i get from this URL https://mrecord.mts.ru/api/v2/numbers

Comment: @Jim Ok, you're right. It's valid JavaScript, but there's an extra comma. Perhaps OP just abbreviated part of it.

Comment: @ZZnOB then please post the full Json and not a part of it ...

Comment: @Jim http://pastebin.com/4gwKGK0j full file

Comment: @ZZnOB now this one is valid :)

Comment: @Jim and how i can get values "9824800036"?

Comment: @ZZnOB check answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used Newtonsoft.Json and was able to read your json with the following code:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile);
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
dynamic value = jsonObj["Value"];

foreach (var val in value)
{
     Console.WriteLine(val.Name);
}
```

You will need to include Microsoft.CSharp as a reference to your project for this to compile.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, if you don't have legal JSON, then you'll need to write your own parser.

This isn't that difficult to do, but you haven't provided a sufficient definition of your source files for me to write it for you. For example, did you really post the correct JSON? Does it always start with `"value"`, and how much of the other stuff is fixed or can vary?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution if you want to use custom parsing :

```
var source = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile);
string pattern = @"""\d{10}""";    // Note: {10} wil match only 10 digit number           
var matches = Regex.Matches(source, pattern);
foreach (var val in matches)
   Console.WriteLine(val);
```